# Can scikit's f1_score's avg macro/micro be used for multi-labeled clustering?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, cluster-analysis

It seems like the scikitlearn's f1_score avg micro/macro (http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.f1_score.html) is based on  multi-label data classifier, but I was wondering if the same could be used for multi-label clustering?

The data I'm working with is clustered using scikit's kmeans on 50.000 timeseries(ts). So I end out with clusters in the form: c1{ts_1, ts_2 ...}, c2{ts_20, ts_21 ...} etc.

Each time series can have one too many labels, which I would like to use as a golden standard for the f1 avg micro and macro scores. A cluster's time series can then be substituted by its labels(L): c1{(L_1, L_2), (L_2), (L_2), (L_3, L_4, L_5)...}

Can the f1 avg micro and macro scores be applied to clustering of such a dataset, or is there other scores i should be looking at instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. Because the clusterings use own "labels" (often 0...k), and there is no 1 on 1 match to classification labels.

Clustering just is nor classification. The term "unsupervised classification" is very misleading, as the differences can be quite substantial. That is why nobody in clustering seems to use this term.

Use any of the established *cluster* evaluation metrics instead.